# Cron and Bash script: impossible to execute

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I've made a bash script that execute a docker command to dump a MySQL database:

**dump_db.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

time=$( date +%Y%m%d%H%M )

currdir=$( pwd )

cat $currdir/container_list | while read container; do
        echo "" | docker exec -i $container mysqldump -u <user> -p<password> <dbname> > $currdir/$container-$time.sql
done
```

**If i try to run the script manually, all works fine**, but if i use `cron`, the script does not execute.

My crontab is:

```
PATH=<same environment>

26 17 * * * /bin/sh /path/to/script/dump_db.sh
```

as you can see, i've tried also to export PATH (and checked it via `env` command in the crontab), but nothing.
I've also tried with these lines

```
26 17 * * * /bin/bash /path/to/script/dump_db.sh
26 17 * * * /path/to/script/dump_db.sh
```

Furthermore, also a simple bash script, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch test_touch.txt
```

does not work, while the simple `touch` command via `cron` it is ok.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: `pwd` echos the current path (not the path in which the script resides, but the path in which the current user sits). Try heading out to root `cd /` and running your script manually `/bin/sh /path/to/script/dump_db.sh`. I think you will find that it doesn't work as `pwd` will be `/` and `/container_list` is not a directory at that level so there is nothing to iterate. The script runs fine, it just doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why are you using `/bin/sh` to execute a script that has a `bash` shebang?

Comment: @JNevill you are my savior. I'm a little ashamed for this error -.-' , btw...thank you! If you post an answer, i'll mark it like right.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if the script has execution permission for other user. 
When you're running manually you're running with the user you're logged in. 
But when its running from Cron its another user. Sot that user has to have the permission to execute that script.

[You may check this post for more help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working)